# Can flutter app query local sqlite database?

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, cross-platform

With a Flutter mobile app can I query a sqlite database located in the `C:/user` path of a computer?

I have a sqlite database located in `C:/users/database/part.db`. Can I query it with a mobile app developed in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sqflite plugin which is a Flutter plugin for SQLite database integration to query a [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) database with a mobile app developed in Flutter.

To use it, you need to add it as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
    dependencies:
      sqflite: <use latest version>
```

And `import` it in your dart file.

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
```

You can see updated sqflite installation document [in here](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite/install)